# ActiveAndroid +SqlCipher

Tags: android

When I run the project after integrating ActiveAndroid+Sqlcipher it is giving error .

I have even included the .so file of SqlCipher in my main project.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.activeandroid.DatabaseHelper
                                                     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
                                                     at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModelClasses(Unknown Source)
                                                     at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModel(Unknown Source)
                                                     at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                     at com.activeandroid.Cache.initialize(Unknown Source)
                                                     at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(Unknown Source)
                                                     at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(Unknown Source)
                                                     at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone please help I am stuck.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Example: https://bitbucket.org/evenos-consulting/org.evenos.android.activeandroid-sqlcipher/src/ec0bd2d7abf5d2bf73230f72529de47a74228694?at=default